# I am having trouble with Pycharm CE after updating to 2023.2.1

Tags: pycharm

I just updated Pycharm CE to 2023.2.1. However, now I am getting an error and am not sure how to resolve this issue.
**virtualenv : error: argument dest: the destination .is not write-able at /Users**
[HERE IS A SCREENSHOT OF THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B00oX.jpg)

I have upated Pycharm before and was able to update the version directly from the app.  This time, when I selected **Check for Updates**, in the PyCharm dropdown menu, I had to reinstall Pycharm CE.  I am guessing this has something to do with my error but I am not sure what exactly is happening or how to fix this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems you are trying to create a virtual environment in `/Users` for which you have no permissions. Select a different venv location, perhaps in the user home?

Comment: Thank you, Pavel!  I reconfigured my venv location and interpreter settings.  I think the update on PC reset some of my settings :)